# Recenter QT/QML Map in Qt 5

Tags: c++, qt

Hello dear Programmers,

what I want to do is to recenter my map with the following QML.
I do have the coordinates as a pair of numbers and not like in the map view example as adress.

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 720
   height: 1280
   title: qsTr("")
    id: root
    Map {
       id: map
       anchors.centerIn: parent;
       anchors.fill: parent
       zoomLevel: 11
       objectName: "mainMap"

      center  {
        id: mapCenter
        latitude : 50.89
        longitude: 11.23
      }
      plugin: Plugin {
          name: "here"
          PluginParameter { name: "here.app_id"; value: "R9qav4Kw6gO5XKSxNiOO" }
          PluginParameter { name: "here.token"; value: "58UCNRCr1dZxhLL2Bmmz3Q" }
          PluginParameter { name: "here.proxy"; value: "system" }
      }
      function setPosition(pos) {
          map.toCoordinate(pos);
           map.update();
      }
}
```

The C++ side is relatively simple in the moment.
This is my best shot until now, changing the latitude and logitude directly seemed to never have worked. What worked in earlier Versions was to create a new Object as coordinates and then give it to the map.

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QObject>
#include <QTime>
#include <QBasicTimer>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QEasingCurve>
#include <QGeoCoordinate>
#include <QtPositioning/private/qgeoprojection_p.h>
#include <QGeoServiceProvider>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QNetworkRequest>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QUrl data("https://lstsim.de/js/dispatch/1.js");
    QNetworkRequest request(data);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    QObject *rootObject = engine.rootObjects().first();
    QObject* mainMapCenter = rootObject->findChild<QObject*>("mainMap");
   if(mainMapCenter != NULL){
       QVariant returnedValue;
       QPoint point(12,12);
       QMetaObject::invokeMethod(mainMapCenter, "setPosition",
       Q_RETURN_ARG(QVariant, returnedValue),
       Q_ARG(QVariant, point));
       qDebug() << "found map";
   }
    return app.exec();
}
```

Like Mentioned befor in earlier Versions this worked:

```
   function centermyposition(){ //sets my position, but only once (do not update automatically)
      var coord = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtMobility.location 1.1; Coordinate{latitude:' + positionSource.position.coordinate.latitude + ';longitude:' + positionSource.position.coordinate.longitude + ';}', positionSource, "coord");
      map.center = coord;
      myMapRoot.updateViewport()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me:

```
ApplicationWindow {

 Location {
        id: mapCentre
        coordinate {
            latitude: -27.5
            longitude: 153.1
        }
    }
    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.centerIn: parent;
        anchors.fill: parent
        zoomLevel: 11
        objectName: "mainMap"

        function recenter(lat,lng) {
           mapCentre.coordinate.latitude = lat
           mapCentre.coordinate.longitude = lng
         }
     }
}
```